# Can I work around ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter, twitter-oauth

Trying get a handle on oAuth by recreating twitter using the omniauth-twitter and twitter gems, and I'm stuck on viewing the tweets of all the users I'm following in my app together in one place. I can view my own tweets and other users' in their own profile fine.

This is the error trace

> NoMethodError in PagesController#home
>
> undefined method `where' for Twitter::Timeline:Class
>
> app/models/twitter/timeline.rb:47:in `from_users_followed_by'
>
> app/models/user.rb:24:in `hub'
>
> app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:5:in `home'

pages_controller.rb

```
def home
  if signed_in?
    @hub_items = current_user.hub.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
end
```

user.rb

```
def hub
  Twitter::Timeline.from_users_followed_by(self)
end
```

timeline.rb

```
module Twitter
 class Timeline
  def self.from_users_followed_by(user)
    followed_user_ids = "SELECT followed_id FROM relationships
                        WHERE follower_id = :user_id"
    Twitter::Timeline.where("user_id IN (#{followed_user_ids}) OR user_id = :user_id",
                            user_id: user.id)
end
end
end
```

** Controllers

hub_controller.rb

```
def show
  @hub_items = []
  render 'pages/home'
end
```

** Views

_hub.html.erb

```
<% if @hub_items.any? %>
  <ol class="microposts">
    <%= render partial: 'shared/hub_item', collection: @hub_items %>
  </ol>
  <%= will_paginate @hub_items %>
<% end %>
```

_hub_items.html.erb

```
<li id="<%= hub_item.id %>">
  <% if @hub_item.any? %>
  <% @hub_item.each do |post| %>
    <% if post.provider == "twitter" %>
      <%= render partial: "users/twitter_post", locals: {post: post} %>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

So, Is there a way to write my self.from_users_followed_by method so that it **doesn't have to inherit from ActiveRecord::Base?** I can give anything else that's needed to figure this out.

Comment: It looks like you're very likely having a namespace collision if you are using a Ruby gem called Twitter (http://sferik.github.io/twitter/ ?) and also trying to call your models Twitter as well.

Comment: Twitter is the name of a folder in my models folder that I keep timeline.rb in. If this is a problem, should I rename the file?

Comment: I understand but it sounds like you're also loading a gem that uses the `Twitter` namespace. I'm not 100% sure if this is allowed but it certainly is a possibility of being an issue. The error `undefined method `where' for Twitter::Timeline:Class` points toward this as `Twitter::Timeline` should have a `where` method IF it is a child class of ActiveRecord

Comment: Ok, If I change it from twitter to anything else, is there still a way to do this without the model inheriting from ActiveRecord::Base?

Comment: If you dont want to inherit from ActiveRecord::Base which I see with your added code that it doesnt.. then you can't use the ActiveRecord methods such as `#where`.

Comment: ok then, Is there a way to work around AR::Base to get the #{followed_user_ids}

Comment: Would scoping this to my user model help?

Comment: Yeah you could Do that

Comment: I'm new to rails so I'm sorry if I'm a bother, but would I be scoping my relationship model to my user model? Also, would it be simpler to write a **join** statement in my hub method. Thanks for the help so far btw.